# Find highlighted text

Tags: c#, ms-word

The following code finds instances of the word "Family" in a Word document. It selects and deletes the instances.  The code works fine, but I want to find all instances of only highlighted words.

```
public void FindHighlightedText()
{
    const string filePath = "D:\\COM16_Duke Energy.doc";

    var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application {Visible = true};
    var doc = word.Documents.Open(filePath);
    var range = doc.Range();

    range.Find.ClearFormatting();
    range.Find.Text = "Family";

    while (range.Find.Execute())
    {
          range.Select();
          range.Delete();
    }
    doc.Close();
    word.Quit(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

Comment: Try recording a macro with the actions you need. The methods called in the VBA are the same ones used by Interop

Comment: which leads to `.Find.Highlight = true`

Comment: So, I'm a bit confused - you don't want to find "Family" but you want to find "highlighted words" - what have you tried along those lines?

Comment: @theMayer if you try to search for highlighted words in Word you'll understand the question. Highlighting isn't a formatting property

Comment: You mean this one? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/find-highlight-property-word

Comment: No, I mean open Word, go to the Find dialog box and try to find highlighted words. You'll understand the confusion then

Comment: I want to find all highlighted words; I was just testing the range.Find.Execute() to make sure I could find text.  My goal is to be able to remove all words highlighted in red.

Comment: @user1331734 record the macro and check the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [Find.Highlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.highlight.aspx) property to `true`.

Interop uses the same objects and methods that are available to VBA macros. You can find the actions, properties you need to perform a task by recording a macro with those steps and inspecting it.

Often, but not always, the properties match the UI. If something is a property in the general Find box, it's probably a property in the `Find` interface as well.

For example, searching only for highlighted words produced this macro :

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
```

Which can be translated to :

```
range.Find.ClearFormatting();
range.Find.Highlight=1;
...
while(range.Find.Execute())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I set the Find.Highlight property = 1 and it works!  Thanks